# Flickering tooltip when hovering over it

Tags: javascript, css, angular, charts, google-visualization

I am getting a flickering tooltip once my mouse hovers over that actual tooltip on a google chart. I have been looking up solutions but have not been able to fix the issue as of yet. Here they [debate about the mouse being below the tooltip element is what is causing the flickering](https://github.com/google/google-visualization-issues/issues/2162). A workaround is represented which perhaps I am not able to implement due to my lack of knowledge on  angular.

```
//Change: 
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});

//To:
google.charts.load('42', {'packages':['corechart']});
```

The way I am loading my chart is just by calling the following in my html component.

```
<google-chart [data]="pieChartData" 
ng-style="svg > g > g:last-child { pointer-events: none }"></google-chart>
```

Another solution presented is to set the `pointer-events` to none in the style. I tried adding these lines to my css component.

```
svg > g > g:last-child { pointer-events: none }
div.google-visualization-tooltip { pointer-events: none }
```

Without any results, I also tried to add `pointer-events: none` within my html component on the tag that I am drawing my PieChart with. Both with 'style' and 'ng-style`. However, I can imagine setting the`pointer-events` to none the tooltip will not show at all, this is an improvement over the correct functionality but nonetheless unwanted.

edit:
I am using the following module: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-google-charts

Comment: The solution mentioned on the github thread works fine for me: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/pm3p4eya/ Your question is about implementing it, but you aren't showing us a [mcve].

Comment: @ChrisG So since this is angular I need to post everything related to charts? That is a lot more then in your minimal example which does not use angular. I have `.piechart svg > g > g:last-child { pointer-events: none }` in `chart.component.css` and wrapped the tag `<google-chart>` in `<div class="piechart">` but there is no improvement. My problem likely lies in my knowledge of angular and how things communicate with each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not surprised anymore. Just as I submit my question I come up with the idea to check out the `ng2-google-charts` module and lookup where it loads the chart. Inside `google-charts-loader.service.js` I changed the version number from `45.2` to `42` which fixes the issue.

```
GoogleChartsLoaderService.prototype.load = function (chartType) {
    var _this = this;
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        if (resolve === void 0) { resolve = Function.prototype; }
        if (reject === void 0) { reject = Function.prototype; }
        _this.loadGoogleChartsScript().then(function () {
            google.charts.load('42', { // <---- version number
                packages: [_this.chartPackage[chartType]],
                language: _this.localeId,
                callback: resolve
            });
        });
    });
};
```

I still appreciate options to get this to work with later versions.

Answer (score 1):

This is just for clarification:
For anyone NOT using angular @Madmenyo shows the solution to this problem in the beginning of his problem statement above.
Swap out whatever version you have in your "google.charts.load" statement for version '42'

```
function loadGraphs() {
  google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawDORCharts); ...
```

Change 'current' above to '42' like below and the tooltips will suddenly behave.

```
function loadGraphs() {
  google.charts.load('42', {'packages':['corechart']});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawDORCharts); ...
```